# libc6 Error while installing or upgrading with apt

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, system-installation, maven

I am currently using the following version of ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
On this machine I am trying to remove an existing maven plugin using
`sudo apt-get autoremove maven`

I am getting the following error: -

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) but 2.27-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Then I tried this as suggested
`sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
libllvm7
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
libc6 libc6:i386
Suggested packages:
glibc-doc glibc-doc:i386 locales:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
libc6 libc6:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 428 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,382 kB of archives.
After this operation, 19.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
(Reading database ... 197197 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring libc6:i386 (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
new libc6:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libc6:amd64 (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_i386.deb (--unpack):
new libc6:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.27-3ubuntu1.4_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I am novice to ubuntu and I dont know how to approach this. Please tell me how to tackle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

This will show you what process is holding the lock:

```
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
                     root      12590 F.... dpkg-preconfigu
```

Note down the PID and kill it with `sudo kill PID` or `sudo kill -9 PID` which in this example is `12590`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Karel, this really helped.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I  had the same error when installing `python3-pip` (`apt install python3-pip`)

If you check closer the error, you are trying to upgrade `libc6 libc6:i386`, so to fix the error, what you can do is to avoid those upgrades.

I've done it like this:

```
apt-mark hold libc6
apt-mark hold libc6:i386
yes | apt install python3-pip --no-upgrade libc6 libc6:i386
```